# Golang aws-sdk-go dynamodb UnmarshalMap type error assignment

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I get the following error: `cannot use dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &item) (type error) as type Item in assignment` when I try assign my struct using the `UnmarshalMap` method.

I get the item from the DynamoDB table here

```
result, err := svc.GetItem(&dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "ForumName": {
                S: aws.String(forumName),
            },
        },
    })
```

And in get the following JSON response body

```
{
   "Item":{
      "Threads":{
         "N":"30"
      },
      "Category":{
         "S":"Amazon Web Services"
      },
      "Messages":{
         "N":"11"
      },
      "Views":{
         "N":"99"
      },
      "ForumName":{
         "S":"AWS Step Functions"
      }
   }
}
```

Now when I attempt to assign my struct

```
    type Item struct {
        ForumName string `dynamodbav:"ForumName,stringset"`
        Category  string `dynamodbav:"Category,stringset"`
        Messages  int    `dynamodbav:"Messages,numberset"`
        Threads   int    `dynamodbav:"Threads,numberset"`
        Views     int    `dynamodbav:"Views,numberset"`
    }

    var item Item

    item = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &item)
```

I get the error here `item = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &item)`

I also tried setting my struct like so

```
    type Item struct {
        ForumName string 
        Category  string 
        Messages  int    
        Threads   int    
        Views     int    
    }
```

Comment: As the error states, [UnmarshalMap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#UnmarshalMap) returns a value of type `error`. Assign the returned value to a variable of type `error` and handle the error as appropriate. 
 Example: `err := dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &item); if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }`.  The value is unmarshaled to `&item`.

Answer (score 0):

Try as Cerise Limón says, to manage the error properly because you are putting a type `error` coming from `dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap` in a pre-defined Item type variable. So it won't compile.